# Socket.IO-Client support for function callback

Tags: android, socket.io

I'm using a Java implementation of `socket.io` for an Android app, but the library doesn't support callbacks.  My server requires the use of callbacks to handle responses for messages I send.

I can't use sequence numbers and match them up myself.

I'm reading a lot of source code to track this down. Does anyone know how `socket.io-clients` send/receive sequence numbers to match to proxies functions on the server side?

Comment: Which socket.io Java library are you using?

Comment: This is the library chosen for me: https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Library. https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync#androidasync-also-supports-socketio

You can use this to send message.

```
 client.emit("new user", data,new Acknowledge() {
    @Override
    public void acknowledge(JSONArray arg0) {
    System.out.println("acknowledge "+ arg0);
}
});
```